# Reproducible Elliptic Curve Digital Signature algorithm parameters in C#

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, ecdsa, elliptic-curve

Using the following code, I can generate the Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA) parameters (i.e., public and private keys).

```cs
using var ecdsa = ECDsa.Create(ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP384);
var publicKey = ecdsa.ExportParameters(false);
var privateKey = ecdsa.ExportParameters(true);
```

This method generates new keys every time, which is the correct choice for many applications. However, in my application, I need to be able to fix the random seed to get reproducible keys.

I have two requirements:

- Using only the built-in methods;
- Cross-platform support.

Any suggestions on how I can generate the reproducible keys?

Comment: Why not just generate them once and then reuse them? What's the point of generating the same key repeatedly, besides burning CPU/GPU cycles?

Comment: The keys should be reproducible given a seed, and the application has various seeds for different purposes.

Comment: Pass an ECCurve with a custom Seed value.

Comment: If you mean creating a pre-compiled list of key-seed pairs, unfortunately, that is not acceptable for my application.

Comment: So you want to reduce a cryptographically strong 384 bit EC key to a weak 32 or 64 bit seed? Defeats the purpose.

Comment: The seed is a string, which is also generated cryptographically strong.

Comment: You can use a password-based key derivation function with random salt for the raw private (48 bytes) key (or a hash-based key derivation function if the key material has sufficient entropy). This raw private key can be wrapped in `ECParameters` and imported with `ImportParameters()`.

Comment: @Topaco, that is an excellent suggestion! Can you please provide a code example for the hash-based key derivation function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raw private EC key is a random byte sequence, e.g. for P-384 consisting of 48 bytes. Analogous to the key derivation of a symmetric key, a key derivation function can be used to determine the same raw private key based on a given key material.
If the key material is a passphrase of insufficient entropy, a password-based key derivation function (such as PBKDF2) should be used in conjunction with a (non-secret) random salt. The raw private key can then be reconstructed using the passphrase and the salt.
If the key material has sufficient entropy, a hash-based key derivation function (HKDF) can be used (see [RFC 5869](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5869)). NET provides an implementation for this as of .NET 5, see [`HKDF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hkdf).

The public key (or the corresponding `ECPoint`) is obtained from the raw private key by multiplying it by the generator point of the respective curve. However, it is not necessary to determine the public key *directly*, as .NET determines it implicitly under the hood (should direct determination be necessary for some reason: as far as I know, .NET does not expose public methods for modular arithmetic, meaning that other libraries would have to be used (e.g. BouncyCastle) to determine the raw public key directly from the raw private key).

As the key material has sufficient entropy according to the question, the following is an example implementation with HKDF. This does not require any additional libraries and works cross platform:

```cs
private static ECDsa CreateKeyViaHKDF(byte[] keyMaterial, ECCurve ecCurve, int size)
{
    ECParameters ecp = new ECParameters();
    ecp.Curve = ecCurve;
    ecp.D = HKDF.DeriveKey(HashAlgorithmName.SHA512, keyMaterial, size, null, null);
    return ECDsa.Create(ecp); 
}
```

Test:

```cs
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
...
byte[] keyMaterial = Convert.FromHexString("d25a4ea14eb6ad223393fd84ab59a62e"); // keyMaterial with sufficient entropy
ECDsa key = CreateKeyViaHKDF(keyMaterial, ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP384, 48);

// Export raw private/public key
ECParameters privateKey = key.ExportParameters(true);
ECParameters publicKey = key.ExportParameters(false);
Console.WriteLine("Private key (raw, Base64):   " + Convert.ToBase64String(privateKey.D));
Console.WriteLine("Public key, X (raw, Base64): " + Convert.ToBase64String(publicKey.Q.X));
Console.WriteLine("Public key, Y (raw, Base64): " + Convert.ToBase64String(publicKey.Q.Y));

// Export keys in PKCS#8 (private key) and SPKI (public key) format 
Console.WriteLine("\nPrivate key (PKCS#8): " + key.ExportPkcs8PrivateKeyPem());
Console.WriteLine("\nPublic key (SPKI): " + key.ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfoPem());
```

Comment: The sample code can be run here online on *Linux/Ubuntu*: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tfuHbu